# Process Java objects

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want use this Java code to process Serialized Java objects from RabbitMQ publisher.

```
            Consumer consumerone = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                        byte[] body) throws IOException {
                    processobjone(body);
                }
            };
            channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_FIRST_NAME, true, consumerone);

            Consumer consumersec = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                        byte[] body) throws IOException {
                    processobjsec(body);
                }
            };
            channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_SEC_NAME, true, consumersec);

// Processing

private void processobjone(byte[] body) {       
        // handle obj
    }

    private void processobjsec(byte[] body) {   
        // handle obj
    }

  .... and many more
```

The issue is that I will have more than 50 types of Java Objects. Is there any design pattern or smart Java way to use for example one Factory method for all methods and reuse the code? I would like just to shrink the Java code with some smart way into several lines. As you can see it's not looking good to have 50 methods for handling the delivery.

Comment: Are the `byte[]` actual serialized Java objects? If so, are they yours to adjust? Does your code fill the AMQP `properties` that are sent?

Comment: @daniu byte[] will be just one Java Object. I'm planning not to set AMQP properties  for now. Can you advice what are the best practices.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the code even does. Do all the processings have to be performed for each object? I initially thought it depended on the type of arriving object which method to call.

Comment: @daniu Yes because the Java objects will be processed to get the values and inserted into database using Hibernate

Comment: And is there a reason the methods aren't just called one after the other in a single consumer, rather than creating a `DefaultConsumer` for each? Either way, are you using Java 8 or above?

Comment: @daniu I want to use individual queue for each Java object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the methods is a `Consumer<byte[]>`, and those need to be assigned to a certain queue name. This is probably best done in a `Map`.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

// ...

Map<String, Consumer<byte[]>> queueToConsumer = new HashMap<>();
queueToConsumer.put(QUEUE_NAME_ONE, this::processobjone);
queueToConsumer.put(QUEUE_NAME_TWO, this::processobjtwo);
// and so on
```

Then you can use this to create the `Consumer`s.

```
queueToConsumer.forEach((queueName, consumer) -> {
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, new DefaultConsumer() {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            consumer.accept(body);
        }
    });
});
```

If you have a name clash with `Consumer` because of `com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer`, you can use declare the map as `Map<String, java.util.function.Consumer<byte[]>>` instead.

Comment: with this code can I have individual queue for each object?

Comment: my idea s to have individual queue as a channel to process Java objects.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "individual queue for each object". Queues are identified by QUEUE_NAME iiuc, so no, this will handle a single queue (as in your code).

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed this in my post. I need to have individual queue for each object.  Thant;s why I want to shrink the code. Can you show me some Java code example how I can archive this?

Comment: I edited the answer. You will not get around to do some kind of mapping. If you're using Spring or something, this could be done less tediously I suppose (but that would be a different question).

Comment: I have a issue wit the code The type Consumer is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <byte[]>

Comment: Then you use the wrong `Consumer`, this is `java.util.function.Consumer<T>`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html.

Comment: Can you please update you code example. Loos like not inly imports I have to edit.

Comment: When I replace the imported package I get `The method add(String, this::process_transaction) is undefined for the type Map<String,Consumer<byte[]>>`

Comment: I updated the answer, see last hint (use `Map<String, java.util.function.Consumer<byte[]>>`).

Comment: I get these errors: The method add(String, this::process_transaction) is undefined for the type Map<String,Consumer<byte[]>> The method basicConsume(String, boolean, Consumer) in the type Channel is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean, new DefaultConsumer(){})

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, needs to be `put`.

Comment: Yes, I notice but after that I get The method basicConsume(String, boolean, Consumer) in the type Channel is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean, new DefaultConsumer(){})

Comment: Probably I need to add some arguments here this::process_transaction(...)?